# Laravel 8: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object while returning results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project which is an Online Forum.

And here is my route to `/` uri:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $threads = App\Models\Thread::paginate(15);
    return view('welcome', compact('threads'));
});
```

And at `welcome` blade:

```
@section('content')
    @include('thread.partials.thread-list')
@endsection
```

And at `thread-list`, I added this:

```
@forelse($threads as $thread)
Posted by <a href="{{route('user_profile',$thread->user->name)}}">{{$thread->user->name}}</a> {{$thread->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
@endforelse
```

But somehow I get this error:

> **ErrorException** Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: thread-list.blade.php)

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to access name from user, but isn't user just a field in the thread table? Like an id for example?

Comment: add your model relationship code and database filed name in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because $thread->user is null which mean the user is being deleted.
you can use one of the following ways:

1. sort out the thread which user not exists in Controller:

   Route::get('/', function () {
   $threads = App\Models\Thread::has('user')->paginate(15);
   return view('welcome', compact('threads'));
   });
2. remove a tag if user not exists:

   @forelse($threads as $thread)
   Posted by
   @if($thread->user)
   user->name)}}">{{$thread->user->name}}
   @else
   anonymous
   @endif
   {{$thread->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
   @endforelse